# Should UML be used for creating GUI's?

Tags: user-interface, uml

Anyone has experience using UML to create a GUI? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Unified Modeling Language (UML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) has nothing to do with user interface design.

UML is a modeling language that can be used to design a software system and the interactions between systems. However, some specific models might be useful in determining how a user (either a person or another system) interacts with your system - [State diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) can be used to show what actions can be performed under certain conditions, [Activity diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) can be used to show workflows, and [Communication diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram) can show how your user interface classes interact with your controllers and how your controllers interact with your models.

If you want to model a GUI, I would look at [prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Prototyping).

Answer (score 2):

UML is a lot of stuff. What exactly where you considering?

A sketch of the GUI on a whiteboard is a good way to describe how it will look. If you make it too formal, people will start to nitpick on things, because it looks final. Instead of telling you that a searchbox should be added, they'll tell you that the icon should be blue, not green. With a simple sketch people realize that it's a WIP, and they'll sketch up their own view very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is using a mockups tool for desiging the GUI before committing it to code. The big benefit of mocking up your GUI before building it in a designer lile Visual Studio is that you can focus on the usability of your screens without getting mired in the details of pixel perfect positioning and color schemes. It's also far easier to edit a mockup than an actual user interface. This gives you the same flexibility in GUIs that UML gives you when desiging algorithms and object models.

My favorite mockup tool [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups).

Here is an example of what it can do:

[image]
<sub>(source: [balsamiq.com](http://www.balsamiq.com/images/bownce.gif))</sub>

Comment: Understood. But UML isn't for desiging GUIs, either.

Comment: Then why do you have this sentence in your answer: "It's kind of like UML for GUIs." No, it's not. At all.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, few people follow the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern, probably because view and controller aspects are nested in GUIs, and because GUI builders make it so easy to just start layout work. But implicitly you are already coding (by defining callback procedures, dependencies, enabling/disabling things and so on).

I prefer the following sequence of steps:

1. Use case diagrams
2. Any of the diagrams Thomas proposed, depending on the problem
3. Class diagram of the controller, containing the elements found necessary in step 2
4. GUI layout and coding.

The nice thing about this procedure is that steps 1-3 can be done independently of any specific GUI toolkit (GTK, Qt, ...).